# Problem In Installing MySql Connector for Python

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

Hi I have just started learning sql language in MySql and have completed basic level of the language.
Now I want to access mysql databases from python. I got to know that we need to install MYSQL_Connector for Python to achieve this goal.
But, When i tried to install python-connector for mysql it gives an error that python version not found/

I tried to install it but it failed even though i have python 3.11.0 installed on my pc.
I tried to Reinstall both python and mYsql but it Doesn't worked.
Please help me with this problem

Answer (score 4):

With the error that you've described, it seems that you're using the Windows MSI installer. But there's an issue in the Connector/Python 8.0.31 installer for Python 3.11, that will be fixed in the upcoming release, see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108911

Meanwhile, the solution is performing the installation using the wheel package, actually it's the recommended way of installing Connector/Python.
As described by Oscar in the bug report above, you can run:

```
Console (CMD or PowerShell)
--------------------------------
 > pip install mysql-connector-python
or
 > python -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```